# SQL Update wont Update

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am currently stuck at the following line:

```
$sqlupdatetb = "UPDATE Text SET Texts = '$text' WHERE '$datetb' = Date AND WHERE $_SESSION['PrID'] = PrID";
```

I cannot find the error. It should add the text into the DB field Text if the Date and PrID matches... but all I get is:

```
 UPDATE Text SET Texts = 'DASDASD\r\nDAS\r\nS\r\nSDSDAS\r\ndasdasdas' WHERE '' = Date
```

Can someone please explain to me where the error is and what it is?

Comment: you posted this similar one earlier http://stackoverflow.com/q/42190881/1415724

Comment: you cant have `WHERE` twice

Comment: you **really** need to read the manuals and the good tutorials

Comment: `WHERE '' = Date` which translates to `WHERE empty/nothing = Date`; what are you trying to do here??

Comment: @nogad Oh, for crying outloud; I didin't even see that. I truly am the blind one *lol*

Comment: @Fred-ii- so bad its hard to cache em all :-)

Comment: Classic case of RTFMs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html --- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimization.html

Comment: really nice sql injection btw; have fun recuperating your db later on, and no idea why you're using `\r\n` - terrible code, simply awful

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, its similiar but not the same... I guess.. since I am still at it and new questions keep popping up. nogad thanks , removed the last. Fred-ii- I have a select field in which the User selects the date he wrote something and wants to edit it. That date is $_POST['Date'] and later $datetb. It should paste the selected date in there and search for it in the db

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks... Well SQL Injection here or there, the site wont go anywhere Online. I am a beginner in PHP and MySQL and I am learning it, for that purpose that "site" exists currently.

Comment: If you're leaning, learn it the right way from the get-go - learn how to use prepared statements with placeholders, it's not something just for "advanced programmers", its something every programmer should know.

Comment: @Qirel I know that now, he might have been able to tell me in a nicer way but whatever, I will change it later on. But first when I cant even get this right, I wont start the next thing. But thanks for your advice, really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

In this query:

```
UPDATE Text SET Texts = 'DASDASD\r\nDAS\r\nS\r\nSDSDAS\r\ndasdasdas' WHERE '' = Date
```

shouldn't there be a value to compare to Date?
something like

```
 UPDATE Text SET Texts = 'DASDASD\r\nDAS\r\nS\r\nSDSDAS\r\ndasdasdas' WHERE '*some_value*' = Date
```

Also, what are the fields of your text table?
Show us more code so we can help you better :D

Comment: `WHERE '*some_value*' = Date` don't look kind of backwards?

Comment: Yeah, there should be some value compared to it, the value is taken from a previous $variable, apparently it wont show there :/ What do you mean fields of your text table? The text table is a simple textarea where the user can Input.

Comment: What fields your database table, called Text, have? Can you show more of your code?